# SAP Cloud Foundry SAPUI5 Fiori Multi Tenant App

Tags: sapui5, sap-cloud-foundry

I'm trying to add the multi-tenancy support for my existing SAPUI5 Fiori apps in cloud foundry.
But I'm unable to find documentation for multi-tenancy of the SAPUI5 Fiori apps.
However, there are many articles for CAP application multi-tenancy.

Currently, I have a provider account and multiple tenant accounts. And my fiori applications are deployed to Provider account

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to have an Approuter module, to be able to isolate each tenants identity provider.

Second thing is just deploy your applications to an HTML5 Application Repository app-host instance and bind HTML5 Application Repository app-runtime instance to your approuter.

Then you will have a multitenant frontend application in SAP BTP CF Runtime.